# showInputMethodPicker from notification not working in Android 9

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie, inputmethodmanager

My app sometimes shows a notification to simplify switching to the app's internal input method. Therefore, I am executing

```
((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).showInputMethodPicker();
```

when the user clicks the notification.

This has worked so far, but does not always work on Android 9: When my app is in foreground, it works. When it is not, nothing happens. On logcat, I see a warning

> "Warning  889 InputMethodManagerService   Ignoring
>   showInputMethodPickerFromClient of uid 10210:
>   com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@edf46f0".

Is there any way to make this work again?

Update: I have tried to create an activity, calling `showInputMethodPicker();` in `onResume()`. This works (if I use `postDelayed()` with a relatively long delay which is unfortunate), but I cannot get the activity to close itself automatically. So this doesn't seem to be a good way.

Comment: Is there any way to make this work again? - probably not, they tightened restrictions for showing IME to fix a bug - https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/eb5706183f62b9230fb1ae9eb22254a062e7869c

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be solved by setting the `WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS` permission for your App.

Unfortunately, this requires issuing one adb command:

```
adb shell pm grant com.name.app android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS
```

where `com.name.app` is the package name of your app.